# How to set LOD specifications for all meshes in unreal at once?

Tags: unreal, level-of-detail

I have a large model and want to avoid separately setting the LOD specifications for each component in the model. Is there are way set LOD specifications for all meshes in unreal at once since I want to set the same specifications for each one? (percentages, how many LOD's, and at what screen distance they kick in, using Unreal's autogenerated LOD's).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware this is not possible, normally changing properties like this would be easily doable through the bulk edit via property matrix, but not for LODs.

The LoD settings you see in the editor on the meshes is not really a property, but just a details panel customization that updates the mesh when one of the properties is changed.

We had a similar thing that we needed and we solved this by writing a custom tool to adjust the LoDs of all selected meshes or in folder.

So to answer this in short, I don't think it's possible without writing a custom tool.